# JQuery each loop concat this.text with string

Tags: jquery, get, concatenation, each

I have a each loop that should send a private message:

```
[...].each(function () { $.get('board.php?func=list&id=' + (this.text) + '&send=Please read the board rules'); });
```

When I do 'alert(this.text);' within the each loop, everything works fine. But when I concatenate it with the string of the get Request, it doesn't work.
Do I miss something?

Comment: What exactly is `this`, show us the scope this is used in? If it's an element, it should probably be `$(this).text()`

Comment: Try defining the url separately and logging it to see where the error lies e.g. `[...].each(function () { var url = 'board.php?func=list&id=' + (this.text) + '&send=Please read the board rules'; console.log(url);  $.get(url); });`

Comment: @adeneo: The data I am working with, comes from another get request. I am now working within the callback function: $(data from get request).find('#boardmembers').children('members').each[...]. The rest is above ;)

Comment: Then you are working with elements, and inside each() `this` will be a native DOM element, which has no `text` property, you should be using `$(this).text()` to get the text, did you try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe writing it a little more verbose with $.ajax makes it clearer why you would you need to use `$(this).text()`, and not `this.text`

```
$(data from get request).find('#boardmembers')
                        .children('members')
                        .each(function() { 
                             $.ajax({
                                 type: 'GET',
                                 url : 'board.php',
                                 data: {
                                        func:'list',
                                        id  : $(this).text(),
                                        send: 'Please read the board rules'
                                 }
                             });
                        });
```

Comment: In future I will just use this style. Helped a lot. Thanks man!